# Can I code objective-c mixing with ruby?

Tags: objective-c, ruby, xcode, cocoa

I'm developing a mac program, some code is much similar so I want to use ruby's meta-programming feature to simplify it.

Can I mix ruby code inside my original xcode project?

I have googled to find a project named MacRuby, but it seems not to be what I want. Because I just want to embed some ruby code, or one or two ruby file in my objective-c project, rather than working with a whole ruby project.

Does anyone have some idea?

By the way, I'm working with cocos2d framework.

So I want the solution not affect my original project.

Comment: MacRuby can mix very well with Objective-C code. If you want something small and embedded, check out mruby (although it's not stable yet).

Comment: @echristopherson, I already have a big project, I just want to use ruby to create some of similar code automatically, MacRuby seems not helpful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XCode is developed by Apple and only recognizes the Objective-C. This is not like Eclipse where you can mix up different interpreters and compilers.

You may create a HTML web application on Ruby, run it on a HTTP server and access from you iPhone/iPad application.

Comment: Not entirely true. Xcode also recognizes C, and I _believe_ C++. Anything that can be compiled with clang.

Comment: c++ as well, the files just have to have the proper extensions.